# Is it possible to use responsive image technic technique for height and width together?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a li element with width:20%; the height is depends from the viewport. On small screen I would like bigger height. Inside I have an image what is responsive. The problem is that when I reduce the height of the li element the image doesn't shrink. I would like to resize the width and height together. CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbbOrb

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1450/600/"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are aware that it is actually working, it's just that the image itself cannot be resized to the height of the li properly without losing it's scale.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an alternative approach you can use to scale images without losing aspect ratio, by setting the background of your `li` to use an image, then accommodating 'responsiveness' by using `background-position:center center` and `background-size:cover`:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqqbhuok/)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 15px solid lightblue;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1450/600/);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes I know that way, but is it possible with images instead of background-image?

Comment: I added max-width and max-height, it looks good but in Firefox the container is larger than the image. (I removed the 20% from li) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJJqzo Do you know why is it happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this instead it will work the way you want it to.

```
li {
  width:20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I need to specify the height. Do you have any idea for fixed height?

Comment: @user1452062 You can't have a fixed height if you want the image to be responsive.

Comment: I can have fixed height for the container, img will shrink.